# uber central api access for customers

Tags: android, api, server, uber-api

We want an automated system to book cabs for our customer through app. Customer can request for a cab in our app and we want server to make an api call to company Ubercentral account. What is the way to access the api for UberCentral ? We don't want this manual effort to book cab for customer every time.

Answer (score 0):

There is not an Uber Central API currently:
https://www.uber.com/business/how-it-works